# How to restore database from postgres backup

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

Homebrew did an automatic upgrade of of `postgresql` , but failed to reload the old databases. I am under the impression that the upgrade process makes a copy of the databases. If this is correct where is the back up stored and how do I reload it?

Comment: there is some issue wth brew. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/60686

Comment: check if this path is available **/usr/local/var/postgres.old**

Comment: postgres.old is available.